# Convert a query object into multi query parameter Swagger

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, openapi, joi

I'am using [joi-to-swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-to-swagger) package to generate a documentation for my api and i'm trying to display query parametres from a query object as an individual query parameters.

this is my Joi object

```
export const leaveEstimatedBalance = {
params: Joi.object({
    uuidSalarie: Joi.string().required(),
    uuidSociete: Joi.string().required(),
}),
query: Joi.object({
    limitByEstimationMonth: Joi.boolean().required(),
    month: Joi.number().integer().max(11).required(),
    newRequestedCurrentLeaves: Joi.number(),
    newRequestedEarnedLeaves: Joi.number(),
    year: Joi.number().required()
})
```

};

and this how i'm using it in swagger schema :

```
   '/leave-request/{uuidSalarie}/{uuidSociete}/estimatedBalance': {
        get: {

            "parameters": [{
                description: "Employee uuid",
                in: "path",
                name: "uuidSalarie",
                required: true,
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                description: "Employer uuid",
                in: "path",
                name: "uuidSociete",
                required: true,
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                "in": "query",
                "name": "query",
                "schema":j2s(leaveEstimatedBalance.query).swagger;,     

            }
            ],
           
            summary: "get leave summary for an employee within a specific employer",
            tags: ["Leave request"],
        },
    }
```

but all i get is an example of my schema in a json object

[image]

any help please